# ASP.NET: ActionLink return relative url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I'm new to working on MVC2 asp.net projects.

I was wondering, is it possible to have an action link like this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("[Add To Cart]", "../StoreCart/AddToCart", new { id = Model.id })%>
```

Note the `../StoreCart`.

Here's a returned URL example (I am currently in StoreScreen when I see the ActionLink, but I would like to get out, "one level up" so to speak):

Bad (404): `http://localhost:8231/StoreScreen/StoreCart/AddToCart?id=9`

Desired: `http://localhost:8231/StoreCart/AddToCart?id=9`

Thanks!

PS: Why can't you just do a php like thing and write a custom `<a href="<%: index + "/StoreCart/AddToCart?id=" + id %>" > add to cart </a>` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ActionLink` is not intended to point to a physical URL, rather a action in a controller.

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("[Add To Cart]", "AddToCart", "StoreCart", new { id = Model.id }, null)%>
```

Note: The final `null` is needed as this override of the `ActionLink` requires it. It is the model, and can be an object or null.

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the ", null" parameter,  I hadn't noticed it :P

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be passing `../StoreCart/AddToCart` as argument to an `ActionLink`. The second argument of an `ActionLink` is the action name and I highly doubt that your action is called `../StoreCart/AddToCart`.

So what you want is (which would use the same controller as the current request url):

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("[Add To Cart]", "AddToCart", new { id = Model.id }) %>
```

and if you wanted to set a specific controller just use the [proper overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx):

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(
     "[Add To Cart]", 
     "AddToCart", 
     "StoreCart", 
     new { id = Model.id }, 
     null
) %>
```

And here's a list of [all available overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) I would recommend you checking out.

Comment: I've already tried that, and thought it's not the right way. BEcause when I use what you suggested, I get this url: `http://localhost:8231/StoreScreen/AddToCart?Length=9` (StoreScreen instead of StoreCart) and also, how about this Lenght=9 thing? It's the length of the parameter string I pass for the routeValue: "StoreCart"

Comment: @Twodordan, oh, that's due to your routing configuration. The ActionLink simply uses your routes.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't see the null

Comment: @Twodordan, yeah, the null at the end indicates the `htmlAttributes` parameter. Allows you to pass stuff like `@class`, etc to this anchor element.